# How to directly/conveniently use variable names as filenames?

Tags: function-construction, expression-manipulation, code-review

#### Purpose

To use variable name as file name conveniently.

#### Code

Special thanks to @J.M.'s tips!

```
Remove@"Global`*"
p = Plot[#, {x, 0, 1}] & /@ {x, 1/x};

SetAttributes[g, HoldAll]
g[p_] := Export[ToString@Unevaluated@p <> ".png", p]

(* Few images: *)
{g@p[[1]], g@p[[2]]}

(* Many images: *)
g /@ Hold @@
    Table["p[[" <> ToString@i <> "]]", {i, Length@p}] //
        ToString // ToExpression // ReleaseHold
```

#### Question

I'm not satisfied with this two lines in the last section of the above code:

```
    Table["p[[" <> ToString@i <> "]]", {i, Length@p}] //
        ToString // ToExpression
```

I believe there are smarter ways to implement that, please teach me, thanks!

Comment: I don't know if you realize that your `p` no longer contains the symbols `p1` or `p2`, which is why you get the results you see when mapping over `p`. Using `Hold[p1, p2]` might be more helpful to you.

Comment: That's what `ReleaseHold[]` is for: `ReleaseHold[{g /@ Hold[p1, p2]}]`. Again, `InputForm[p]` will reveal at once that you can't use `p` to refer to `p1` and `p2`.

Comment: @J.M. So how to directly/conveniently use variable names as filenames?

Comment: Wasn't my last comment clear? Using your `g[]`: `p = Hold[p1, p2]; ReleaseHold[{g /@ p}]`

Comment: Please clean it up a little, make a clear question with a nice use case example and self answer with whatever fits your needs. Otherwise it will be closed as too localized / not clear as in this for it won't help future visitors.

Comment: @Kuba Is it okay now?

Comment: @ooo by self answer I meant to move solution to an answer. And if those questions are not related they should not be inside one topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something in this line might do:

```
SetAttributes[ g, HoldFirst ];
g[ sym_ ] := With[
  {
    baseFileName = SymbolName @ Unevaluated @ sym,
    ext = ".png"
  },
  Switch[ sym,
    { __Graphics }, 
      Range@Length@sym // Scan[ Export[ baseFileName <> ToString @# <> ext, sym[[#]] ] & ],
    _Graphics, Export[ baseFileName <> ext, sym ]
  ]
]
```

With a single plot this will then be immediately exported, while with a list of plots (e.g. `Graphics`), the symbol's name will be given an additional counter (e.g. p1.png).

```
SetDirectory @ NotebookDirectory[];
g[p]
(* will write p1.png and p2.png *)
```

Comment: @ooo Sorry for being a bit late to the party. Maybe this answer is still helpful?

Comment: Sorry for being a month late to sign in Stack Exchange. 