# Is it impossible to implement "parameter self-referencing" in the function body?

Tags: function-construction, expression-manipulation

(*Moved from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/167552/18) as [@Kuba's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167552/problems-with-functions-parameters-in-definition-and-arguments-in-execution#comment443599_167552).*)

#### Purpose

Only set one formal parameter in the function definition (`f[...]`), which can be passed like a `List` to the function body.

#### Code

```
f[k1_: x, k2___] := Plot[k1, {x, 0, 10}, k2]

f[]
f[Sinc[x], ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", Axes -> False]
```

#### Question

How can I implement the following form (using `k[[...]]`)?

```
f[k___ : x] := Plot[k[[1]], {x, 0, 10}, k[[2]]]
```

Comment: I am not sure but shouldn't you wrap the `Sequence` `k` in `{}` in order to use `Part`? I mean something like `f[k___ : x] := Plot[{k}[[1]], {x, 0, 10}, {k}[[2]]]` .

Comment: Note the triple-underscore pattern `k___` matches an empty sequence, such as the arguments of `f[]`, so the default `x` in `k___ : x` is never used; I think you want two underscores `k__ : x`.  In the single argument case, e.g., `f[x^2]`, you cannot use `k[[2]]` or `{k}[[2]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that you want the simplicity of [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) syntax combined with features of pattern-based function definitions, and your acceptance of Michael's answer seems to confirm this.

If so I suggest a different format that the one shown.  I recommend passing all arguments to a single `Function` rather than using multiple Functions throughout your right-hand-side.

```
f[k__: x] := Plot[#, {x, 0, 10}, ##2] &[k]

f[]

f[Sinc[x], ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Here's one way, but not using `Part` (cannot use `Part[.., 2]` when the first argument has length `1`):

```
ClearAll[f];
f[k__: x] := Plot[# &[k], {x, 0, 10}, Evaluate[##2 &[k]]]
```

Some alternatives:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[k__: x] := ReleaseHold@Insert[Hold[Plot[k]], {x, 0, 10}, {1, 2}]

ClearAll[f];
f[k__: x] := Plot[# &[k], {x, 0, 10}, Evaluate@Drop[{k}, 1]]    (* see note 3 *)
```

Notes:

1. The triple-underscore pattern `k___` matches an empty sequence, such as the arguments of `f[]`, so the default `x` in `k___ : x` is never used.  With two underscores `k__ : x`, the default `x` is used when the length of the argument sequence is less than `1`.
2. In the single argument case, e.g., `f[x^2]`, the expressed desire to use `k[[2]]` would result in an error if the length of `k` is less than `2`, even if `{k}[[2]]` were used.
3. In the last alternative, one might apply `Sequence` to the result of `Drop` (`Evaluate[Sequence @@ Drop[{k}, 1]]`) to be more exact.  Since `Plot` accepts a `List` of options, the code works as is in this use case.  In another application, `Sequence` may be necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how we can use `Part`:

```
Clear[f]
f[k___] := f[{k}]
f[k_List] := With[{
   k1 = k[[1]],
   k2 = Quiet@Check[k[[2]], ## &[]]
   },
  Plot[k1, {x, 0, 10}, k2]
  ]
```

`## &[]` is the [vanishing function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3705/731). Example:

```
f[x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f[x, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Red}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Also

```
ClearAll[f];
f[k__: x] := Plot[{k}[[1]], {x, 0, 10}, Evaluate[Rest[{k}]]]

f[]
```

[image]

```
f[Sin[x], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Frame -> True]
```

[image]